# Changing Qt stylesheet to dark mode

Tags: front-end, user-interface

This question follows on from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/254104/57593). (Linux)

I am not asking how to change the background colour. Is it possible to change the theme of the GUI on the outside? It looks horrible having a light interface and dark notepad. I think a material dark theme would be really nice.

[image]

My question is short but I don't think anything else needs to be said. Please let me know otherwise. If someone experienced on this site could help me with which tags to use, that would be appreciated.

EDIT: progress

[image]

I am using [this](https://pastebin.com/RBwJAYBC) modified frontend.css in .Mathematica/Frontend/frontend.css currently

Comment: On Linux, version 12.3, [it is possible](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/254104/57593). No idea if so for Windows (which I assume you are running).

Comment: @CarlLange What makes you assume that? Thanks for the link, I can make some bits dark but there still a lot of light bits. See post

Comment: Well, you didn't mention which OS you were using in your question, and your screenshot looked Windows-y to me :) I'm afraid you will need to do quite a bit of experimentation to find the correct Qt CSS classes to colour - it took me a while to come up with the example in the answer I linked. Perhaps you can update your question to more directly ask how to change specific UI elements, because otherwise "Can the GUI style be changed" is more-or-less a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: About student's toolbar: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9471/5478

Comment: @Kuba Awesome, getting closer